# Multiple SQL Tables that can Log In to the Website

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have multiple tables for a website that I am building. So when a user logs in, I use the PHP Session, so when I want to get a user I would normally use:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

I also have a table called representatives, who can also log in which I would select by doing:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM representatives WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

But in the user section I want to make sure the user logged in isn't a representative, and in the representative section I want to make sure the user logged in isn't a user. So how do I find out what kind of account the user is using, and select my mySQL query from the right table? Would I have to make one big table that would just carry all of the information, and then a type field that would denote if the user was a regular user or a representative? Or is there a way to find out what type of user it is while keeping both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a session variable

```
$_SESSION['rep'] = FALSE
```

and set it to true if they are a rep and perform a check on that variable?